# SharePoint App Part is not available after App reinstall

Tags: .net, sharepoint, add-in

I have a custom app developed for SharePoint site which contains of App Part and Web Part items.
Once it is installed first time ever - everything is OK and both App and Web parts are available to select when editing SharePoint pages.
After that, I have removed the app and installed it again. Now I see that my app is successfully installed. But when I go to page editing I can't find App Part in the list of App Parts. However, I still do have the corresponding Web Part available.

Why сan't I see my app part in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say “I have removed the app and installed it again.” Did you also deleted the App from the second stage (site collection level) recycle bin prior to re-installing?

It is very possible that there are remnants of the initial App that have not been completely cleared from the system that are causing a conflict.

[note: Going forward you should consider posting your questions/issues on sharepoint.stackexchange.com which is actively monitored by members of the SharePoint product team.]

Comment: Thanks! This is the thing which caused me troubles: I had to clear recycle bin prior to new installation.